# Is it possible to chown a file, based on numeric UID, to a user that does not yet exist?

Tags: chown

For example, for managing a disk partition for another system where the user exists. I know I can simply create a user temporarily but I find this question interesting.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, you can `chown` to a numerical UID that does not have a corresponding user.

Comment: I tested before I asked: `chown \#1005 file` returns `chown: invalid user: ‘#1005’`.

Comment: Do not use an octothorpe; it is not a number.  Just use the number, e. g. `sudo chown 1005 /path/to/file`.

Comment: According to this logic, `sudo` thinks it's a number. Furthermore, it thinks groups of digits that don't start with a *number sign* are not numbers. :)

Comment: I first tried `chown 1005 file`, by the way. It didn't work, for an unrelated reason, but I blamed it on the missing number sign. You have to at least use `./file`, apparently for chown to be able to tell which of the two is the user. Just so you (reader) know.

Comment: @glarry I do not have to use `./`. Is the file name really `file`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging No, and it was a very well hidden typo, if you ask me. The fact that I used tab completion after `./` made the difference.

Answer (score 35):

`chown UID:GID fileName` can be done either with numbers or username or groupname

ex: `chown 1000:1000 dirname` is valid

you may have to reset the directory permission with `chmod 755` for example after doing it to get access on it

### Hints

- You can check user id with `id someUsername`
- You can check group id with `gid someUsername`
- You can change permissions only on directories with `find someLocation -type d -exec chown 1000:1000 {} \;`

Comment: Using variables `chown -R $HOST_USER_ID:$HOST_GROUP_ID /usr/bin/mariadb/install/data` gives me an error `chown: invalid spec: '1000:'` sous ` `Lubuntu 16/04`

Comment: I could work around the issue by doing two distinct commands `chown -R $HOST_USER_ID /usr/bin/mariadb/install/data; 
chgrp -R $HOST_GROUP_ID /usr/bin/mariadb/install/data; `

Comment: @Stephane your UID and GID must be the number of the group/id you want to change, and is setted into `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` or either by other system like ldap, you can refer to commands like gentent to have more infos about that.